# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdots (3n+1)}{n^5}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdots (3n+1)}{n^5}$$

this question comes right after the question that asks me to prove it with the limit comparsion test. I need to prove that it's divergent.

The limit comparsion test states that in $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$, if $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, then $\sum b_n$ convergent $\implies$$\sum a_n$ convergent. How can I modify this theorem to prove divergence? Also, is is possible to prove the series above is divergent using this test?

Comment: It seems offhand the term being summed doesn't approach zero. [factorials increase faster than powers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to write expressions
with "..." in terms os
$\sum$ and $\prod$.

In this case

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdots (3n+1)}{n^5}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^n (3k+1)}{n^5}\\
&\gt\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (3k+1)}{n^5}\\
&\gt\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (3k)}{n^5}\\
&=\dfrac{3^nn!}{n^5}\\
\end{array}
$

and this diverges
extremely rapidly -
so much so that
it will diverge
for any
$n^m$
for fixed $m$
in the denominator.

As a matter of fact,
since $3 > e$
and
$n! > (n/e)^n$,
this still diverges
if the denominator is
$n^n$.

Comment: isn't there a way to do it that requires the divergence of a more simple series? The following exercises in my list ask me to prove the divergence of one similar to this you showed me.

Comment: or you're talking about divergence of the limit of $\dfrac{3^nn!}{n^5}$? in this case I think I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test zaps this one right off the bat.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n+4)}{(n+1)^5}\frac{n^5}1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n+4}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^5}=\infty$$
So the series diverges. Note how the ratio test created a context where most of the factors of the product canceled out.